# How to use active record model in ruby script with if model is in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model is defined like this in rails codebase

```
module A 
  class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Now I am writing an external ruby script, which connects with active record.

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'postgresql',
  database: 'xxxx',
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx'
)

module A
  class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.do_something
        A::B.all.each do |record|
          #do something
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

A::B.do_something
```

I am getting relation B's does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure, But I think on method `self.do_something` you don't need to call `A::B`, try `self.all.each do |record|`

Comment: Yes, above comment is correct - you are already inside of `A::B` so just call `self.all` instead.

Comment: that did not work .. it said same relation B does not exist. However, in the self.do_something, I had byebug and inspected self .. it said call A::B.connection to establish a connection ..

Comment: Can you copy / paste the exact error ?